# Overloading operator [] in class, so it can return object from array that is in template class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, operator-overloading

```
template <class T> 
class Planer{
    T array;
    int max_stavki;
    int broj_stavki;

    public:

        Planer()
       {
            max_stavki = 100;
            array = new T[max_stavki];
            broj_stavki = 0;
        }
        ~Planer()
        {
            delete[] array;
        }
        void add(T& x){
            if (broj_stavki==max_stavki){
                throw NO_SPACE();
            }
            else{
                array[broj_stavki] = x;        // here i get error
                broj_stavki++;
            }
        }
    };
```

In template class i need to create array of objects of this class.

```
class Ispit{
        char* naziv;
        int sifra = -0001;
        char* datum;
        int vreme;
};
```

But when i want to use function add from template class this error pops up:

> Error   C2676   binary '[': 'Ispit' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I tried something like this in template class. But error is still there.

```
Planer<T>& operator [] (int x){
    return array[x];
};
```

I think i need to overload operator [] in class Ispit too but i don't know how.

Thank you guys in front!

Comment: What is `niz`? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Niz is array but in my language. I forgot to translate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Planer<Ispit>`'s `array` member is of type `Ispit`, which isn't actually an array. What did you intend for the type of `array` to be? Potentially:

```
template <class T> 
class Planer
{
    T* array; // NOTE THAT I MADE THIS A POINTER
    int max_stavki;
    int broj_stavki;
public:
    Planer() {
        array = nullptr;
        broj_stavki = 0;
        max_stavki = 0;
    }
    ~Planer() {
        clear();
        delete[] array;
    }
    Planer(Planer&& other) noexcept {
        array = other.array;
        broj_stavki = other.broj_stavki;
        max_stavki = other.max_stavki;
        other.array = nullptr;
        other.broj_stavki = 0;
        other.broj_stavki = 0;
    }
    Planer& operator=(Planer&& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(array, other.array);
        std::swap(array, other.broj_stavki);
        std::swap(array, other.max_stavki);
        other.clear();
    }
};
```

Comment: I forgot to copy default constructor sorry.